# providing a constructor for a scala trait

Tags: scala, constructor, traits

[SIP 25](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/trait-parameters.html) will allow a trait to have a constructor.  Until that is implemented what would be a good workaround?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the only workaround is to define some abstract methods in the trait that resemble constructor params and override them in concrete implementation:

```
trait A {
  def message:String
}

val a = new A {
  override val message = "Hello!"
}
```

In scala the whole body of your class/trait is the constructor. So basically you use the same approach:

```
class B (override val message:String) extends A

val b = new B("Hello!")
```

Comment: What if I want to define `class B extends A` and have `A` providing a default constructor for it (as if `A` was an `abstract class`).